# parse date without time in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-datepicker

Can anyone help me with react calendar dates? I am showing a search filter where I am using :

for this I am using react useState :

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<Date | null >();

<Input label="selected on" type="date" value={startDate} />
```

Now, after selection, it is coming as UTC date with time as follows:

```
http://localhost:10000/candidates/projects?page_number=1&page_size=20&selected__date__option=2022-05-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

I want only date from this and for that I am using following code:

```
 const convert = (str: Date): Date => {
 const date = new Date(str),
       mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
       day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
       return  new Date([date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-"));
};
```

but the return type is `string` and useState looks for `Date` type.
So, can anyone point what I am missing here?

I want selected__date__option=2022-05-26 of type `Date`

Comment: `return new Date([date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-"));`

Comment: What is an example your expected returned date?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi : thanks but it is still it is sending as selected__date__option=2022-05-25T00:00:00.000Z, I want only date portion.

Comment: @soloko : thanks, I want selected__date__option=2022-05-26

Comment: `selected__date__option=2022-05-26 ` is not a `Date` object ? your question is vague, do you want your state to be Date or string?  how the input of type date, returns that URL?  there is something wrong with your code snippet.

Comment: If you're using react-calendar and depending on your use case, it looks like you can pass in strings and might not need to have the return type of `Date`.

Comment: AFAIK any formatting of a `Date` object will result in a `string` value.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi: It is possible that my question looks vague from your point of view but does that mean it is eligible for negatives? I dont think so. What you can do instead of downgrading you can suggest edits rather.

Comment: @Chandan did you try using type `string` instead of `Date`?

Comment: @soloko yes : I did and let me add the code and result.

Comment: Hope that worked

Answer (score -1):

You can use this action

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date(str))
```

Check out this documentation on MDN as well => [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: thanks but it is throwing error when I am setting it  ````setStartDate(Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date(str)));  ````         
 using Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date | null | undefined>'.

Comment: Agree with @Chandan, this still returns a string